# Set computer to suspend after a certain time when not logged in?

Tags: power-management

I realize that you can set the power preferences for when to shutdown, suspend, and spin down hard disks and so on.

However, I find that seems to only work when I've logged in and then leave the computer - the power will suspend after the specified time, for example.

If I just turn on the computer and not log in, then it stays on indefinitely.

Is there a way to set the power preferences for the computer when no one is logged in?

The reason I keep the power on without logging in is to use this particular computer as my file server. I'd like it to suspend at night when I go to bed, but, each morning when I check on it, my computer is still on.

I'm using LMDE2.